# Mobile Screen orientation lock not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-orientation, mobile-browser

I'm trying to lock screen orientation using the Screen Orientation API as specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation
and here: https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#examples

The API is still in Working Draft, but it shows that Chrome and Firefox support it but I can't get it to work.

I tried the following:
1)

```js
screen.orientation.lock('portrait').catch(function() { /*Do Nothing*/ });
```

2)

```js
screen.lockOrientationUniversal = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;

if (screen.lockOrientationUniversal(["portrait"])) {
  // orientation was locked
} else {
  // orientation lock failed
}
```

But its not working on chrome mobile.

Comment: Having the same issue, I am wondering if you solved.

Comment: @Téwa no ,I havn't . We've moved this required to backlog until the working draft becomes a standard

Answer (score 1):

For chrome and native browsers, like samsung internet, you first need to access fullscreen before you're able to set an orientation lock, this can be done by document.body.requestFullscreen which will return a promise. When successful you are able to lock orientation.