# Lock the orientation of a website made in Webflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to lock the orientation of my website to Portrait mode as there is no point having a Landscape mode on it. Two options works for me:

1. Completley locking the orientation so on a user's screen rotation event, nothing happens (menaning, a website stays in Portrait mode).
2. Making some good looking message that appears only when an user is in Landscape mode.

I tried looking for an answer here in Stack Overflow, but nothing helped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the lock function of the ScreenOrientation API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock

```js
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

But be aware that it is not support on every browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Orientation_API

And you might have to request fullscreen view first as mentioned by this user:

> For chrome and native browsers, like samsung internet, you first need
> to access fullscreen before you're able to set an orientation lock,
> this can be done by document.body.requestFullscreen which will return
> a promise. When successful you are able to lock orientation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67080112/1375229